# Is the sentence below right? Does it sound idiomatic?

Tags: grammar

My friend said
*I'm with you*

I replied

What do I do of you? (Does it sound right)

It means what good does being with you do me.

Comment: Your sentence does not make sense and answerers will have trouble correcting it because your meaning is not clear. Consider updating your post with more content.

Comment: It means what good does being with you do me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who is speaking, either:

> What do I do **for** you?

or

> What do you do **for** me?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better, although a bit too direct, to "what good does that do?" because it address the scenario of the person working with you and so on.

Comment: This is awfully rude, but it is what the speaker wanted to say according to his comment. The person is offering help and you say that his help is worthless and not needed.